# Send the values ​of several columns of the table Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

i want Send the values ​​of several columns of the table ("id", "meter_id", "State", "date", "VII1", "VII2", "VII3", "VII_avg")
here is my code:

```
class VAndI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = PowerMeter.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5].values("id", "meter_id", "State", "date", "VII1", "VII2", "VII3", "VII_avg")
        serializer = VAndISerializer(instance=queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

but got this ERROR:

`'int' object has no attribute 'pk'`

here is my serializer:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)


class VAndISerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PowerMeter
        fields = ["id", "meter_id", "State", "date", "VII1", "VII2", "VII3", "VII_avg"]
```

Please note that with this model and serializer, I get the data of all the columns, but in this case, I only want the information of the specified columns.

```
class VAndI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = PowerMeter.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5].values("id", "meter_id", "State", "date", "VII1", "VII2", "VII3", "VII_avg")
        serializer = VAndISerializer(instance=queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializer:

```
class PowerMeterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PowerMeter
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Share the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [*don't* use `.values()` <sup>[django-antipaterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html): `.values()` provides dictionaries, and other native types, it is a [*primitive obsession* antipattern <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) and will for example for `ForeignKey`s return their primary key, not the corresponding model item.

You thus can work with:

```
class VAndI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = PowerMeter.objects.order_by('-id')[:5]
        serializer = VAndISerializer(instance=queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and if `meter_id` is a `ForeignKey`, we can add the data in the same query as:

```
class VAndI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = PowerMeter.objects.select_related('meter_id').order_by('-id')[
            :5
        ]
        serializer = VAndISerializer(instance=queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If you want to limit the fields, as your `DynamicFieldsModelSerializer` seems to want to do, you are supposed to list the allowed fields when *constructing* the serializer:

```
class VAndI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = PowerMeter.objects.select_related('meter_id').order_by('-id')[
            :5
        ]
        serializer = VAndISerializer(
            instance=queryset,
            many=True,
            fields=[
                'id',
                'meter_id',
                'State',
                'date',
                'VII1',
                'VII2',
                'VII3',
                'VII_avg',
            ],
        )
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based API views (CBV) often have a `…APIView` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `VAndIAPIView`, instead of <s>`VAndI`</s>.